# selenium test case to select submenus from main menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am trying to write a selenium test case for selecting mean from the menu bar following to that to select submenu also.

Please find my menu structure below.

[image]

Please  find my below code that am able to select `Admin` menu after that i was not sure how to select `Default` and its submenu `DSD Defaults`.

am using selenium webDriver.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

feature file

```
When I click on admin menu
When I click on defaults
And I click on dsd defaults
```

Steps file

```
@When("^I click on admin menu$")
public void openAdminMenu() {
    systemDefaultPage.clickAdmin();
}
```

Java file

```
@Autowired
public BasePage(TestWebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

@FindBy(id = "Admin")
private WebElement adminLink;

public void clickAdmin() {
    waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    assertThat("Admin Link is Not Present", adminLink, isDisplayed());
    driver.click(adminLink);
}
```

*** Update 1 ***

```
public class TestWebDriver {
  @Getter
  private WebDriver driver;
  private static final long defaultTimeout = 100;

  @Autowired
  public TestWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

 public void wait(WebElement webElement) {
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN))); // getting message on this line.
  }
}
```

BasePage.java

```
public void clickAdminDefaults() {
  waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
  assertThat("Admin Defaults Link is Not Present", adminDefaultsLink, isDisplayed());
  driver.click(adminDefaultsLink);
  driver.wait(adminDefaultsLink);
}
```

Getting the below message for the `WebDriverWait` implementation

```
The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can try below code:
Steps file

```
    @When("^I click on defaults$")
    public void clickDefauts() {
    systemDefaultPage.clickDefaults();
    }

    @When("^I click on dsd defaults$")
    public void clickDsdDefauts() {
    systemDefaultPage.clickDsdDefaults();
    }
```

Java file

```
    @FindBy(id = "defaults")
    private WebElement defaultsLink;

    public void clickDefaults() {
    waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    assertThat("defaults Link is Not Present", defaultsLink, isDisplayed());
    driver.click(defaultsLink);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "DSDdefaults")
    private WebElement dsdDefaultsLink;

    public void clickDsdDefaults() {
    waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    assertThat("dsdDefaults Link is Not Present", dsdDefaultsLink, isDisplayed());
    driver.click(dsdDefaultsLink);
    }
```

Note: I've added dummy locators for defaultsLink and dsdDefaultsLink. Update it and execute scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just the same way you click the `adminLink`. You might want to introduce [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that the next sub-menu level is present/visible/clickable

```
@FindBy(id="someid")
WebElement dsdDefaults;

public void clickAdmin() {
    waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    driver.click(adminLink);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dsdDefaults))
} 

public void clickDsdDefaults() {
    dsdDefaults.click();
}
```

Also be aware that according to the [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) best practices you should not be having any assertions in the Page Object files. Instead you could come up with a helper method like:

```
public boolean isAdminLinkVisible() {
    return adminLink.isDisplayed();
}
```

and use it in your test code like:

```
Assert.assertFalse(systemDefaultPage.isAdminLinkVisible(), "Admin link is visible although it should be hidden");
```

Comment: Am following your way of implementation. Am getting this message during the implementation `The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (void)`. I have updated the same in details in my questions. Not sure how to implement this.